# Can't submit transaction on Ada on Babbage era. BabbageOutputTooSmallUTxO error

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I'm following the official documentation to send a transaction but I'm still getting the same issue even after to double checked my `protocol.json`. Based on the protocol, it's supposed to be `"minUTxOValue": 1000000`

On my account on the mainnet we can see my UTXO

```
// cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --mainnet

                           TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0c1188f9b5eed8ed8c4b7031ba0bd05cd3d38fea947f1acb1467bcc5baba9583     0        40000000 lovelace + TxOutDatumNone
e663b2e14f180ae341a49bcbde247d074d944942cc3b8794277645ac1e49d377     0        8336205 lovelace + TxOutDatumNone
```

And I'm running this to submit my transaction:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    --tx-in 0c1188f9b5eed8ed8c4b7031ba0bd05cd3d38fea947f1acb1467bcc5baba9583#0 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment2.addr)+20000000 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+20000000 \
    --invalid-hereafter 0 \
    --fee 0 \
    --out-file tx.draft
```

I know the fees can change but keep in mind I'm using the most recent everytime.

```
cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
    --tx-body-file tx.draft \
    --tx-in-count 1 \
    --tx-out-count 2 \
    --witness-count 1 \
    --byron-witness-count 0 \
    --mainnet \
    --protocol-params-file protocol.json
```

The result for this one is: 176765

```
expr 40000000 - 20000000 - 176765
```

For this one the result will be: 19823235.

Then, to update my draft I'm doing this:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    --tx-in 0c1188f9b5eed8ed8c4b7031ba0bd05cd3d38fea947f1acb1467bcc5baba9583#0 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment2.addr)+20000000 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+19823235 \
    --invalid-hereafter 75301753 \
    --fee 176765 \
    --out-file tx.draft
```

Finally I'm signing and sending like this:

```
// to sign
cardano-cli transaction sign \
    --tx-body-file tx.raw \
    --signing-key-file payment.skey \
    --mainnet \
    --out-file tx.signed

// to submit
cardano-cli transaction submit \
    --tx-file tx.signed \
    --mainnet
```

The result is every time is:

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (BabbageOutputTooSmallUTxO [((Addr Mainnet (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "fe424f32d70231494b27921b57a2485fe4e293ae76b7620216703f9c")) (StakeRefBase (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "5d452ab59c3d40e339da2cc8fe5b57d280363eddd5152374adc4cd23"))),Value 826271 (fromList []),NoDatum,SNothing),Coin 969750)])),UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (FromAlonzoUtxoFail (OutsideValidityIntervalUTxO (ValidityInterval {invalidBefore = SNothing, invalidHereafter = SJust (SlotNo 75259418)}) (SlotNo 75302578))))])
```

This is my environment:

```
cardano-cli 1.35.3 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
```

I was wondering if it's an issue from Cardano because I'm clearly following the official documentation.
Thank you so much to the people who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building tx.draft then signing tx.raw. Check you're not using an old txbody.

Comment: Thank you so much mate <3